# Is there any way to hide sign up link from default amplify sign in form?

Tags: android, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

[amplify default sign in user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRJ0a.jpg)

I want to hide sign up link from sign in form. because in my project user is not allowed to create an account. therefore how can i remove this link from that?

1. I tried to change style sign up link but it doesn't work. i can only style buttons, labels and input fields only.
2. I tried to hide all components from sign up form. i hided labels and inputs. but i couldn't change sign up button.

Answer (score 0):

If you change AmplifyTheme to a customTheme and make the changes below

```css
sectionFooterLink: {
...AmplifyTheme.sectionFooterLink,
color: 'transparent',
}
```

Don't forget to export App with `{theme: customTheme}`.